# Get all files contains date value less than an input date

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell

I have 1000's of files .txt files in a folder:

The `ls` output of the folder looks like:

```
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-03-06-23.55.05.436-+0000_2016-09-07-05.31.47.105-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-03-06-23.55.05.436-+0000_2016-09-07-05.27.47.000-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-03-06-23.55.05.436-+0000_2016-09-07-05.25.46.891-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-03-06-23.55.05.436-+0000_2016-09-07-05.23.46.788-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-07.02.41.320-+0000_2016-07-27-07.07.21.784-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-07.02.41.320-+0000_2016-07-27-07.05.22.541-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-07.02.41.320-+0000_2016-07-27-07.02.41.320-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-06.22.49.534-+0000_2016-07-27-07.01.32.824-+0000.txt
```

**Now, I want to list all files that have date value less than an input date**

For eg:

My Input date is: 2016-08-11

I want the result:

```
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-07.02.41.320-+0000_2016-07-27-07.07.21.784-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-07.02.41.320-+0000_2016-07-27-07.05.22.541-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-07.02.41.320-+0000_2016-07-27-07.02.41.320-+0000.txt
2-20160329050200862185.instan-methodstack_2016-04-27-06.22.49.534-+0000_2016-07-27-07.01.32.824-+0000.txt
```

The comparison date value has to check after the string starting with **+0000_**

I tried multiple commands, but nothing worked.

```
ls | awk ' { i = substr($0, 73, 10); cond = "2015-09-07"; if expr "$i" "<" "$cond" > /dev/null; then print($0); fi }'
ls | awk ' { i = substr($0, 73, 10); if ( (date -d i +"%Y%m%d") -lt 20160907 ) print($0) endif; print("\n") }'
```

Please help.

Comment: try `ls | awk '{ i = substr($0, 73, 10) } i < "2016-08-11" '` assuming http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs doesn't trip you

Comment: @Sundeep thank you for your comment. It is working. Do I need to convert the dates to timestamp value for comparison? Make it an answer.

Comment: added as answer, also you might want to refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents , shell programming is different than awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is not error prone in this case:

```
ls | awk '{ i = substr($0, 73, 10); if(i < "2016-08-11") print }'
```

or the equivalent

```
ls | awk '{ i = substr($0, 73, 10) } i < "2016-08-11" '
```

- `i = substr($0, 73, 10)` saves the extracted date to variable `i`
- `i < "2016-08-11"` if this condition is true, print input line

Since the date is in **YYYY-MM-DD** format, a simple string comparison will work without need of any conversion

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command

you can give the date input as yyymmdd format in awk command

```
ls *.txt > all_files.txt
awk -F_ -vin_date="20160427" '{split($2,a,"-");date=a[1]a[2]a[3];if(date+0<in_date)print}' all_files.txt
```

Comment: For me, not working

Comment: when you say.. not working.. you have to provide more details.. is any error ? is all_files.txt contains only the filenames?

Comment: yes there is only filenames. How do I execute the code in terminal?

Comment: just copy paste the code in terminal. make sure you change the date in_date

Comment: No output is showing. Note that, I need to compare the date from the string after a match +0000_ in the filename. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Combining `match` and `substr` in `awk` giving me the desired result:

```
ls | awk 'match($0,"\+0000_"){i = substr($0,RSTART+6,10)} i < "2016-08-11" '
```